# How can I convert a file path into different parts?

Tags: php, arrays, string, path, explode

I want to create a small code that echo a filepath with anchor elements for every singe path directory.

So all I want is to explode a path to the single values.
example:

```
$file_dir = "1/2/3/4";
```

the result:

```
<a href="1">1</a>/
<a href="1/2">2</a>/
<a href="1/2/3">3</a>/
<a href="1/2/3/4">4</a>/
```

In the browser: 1/2/3/4 (every number is click able and will link the user to that directory)

My current code:

```
$file_dir = "1/2/3/4";
$output = array();
$devisions = explode('/', $file_dir);
foreach ($chunks as $i => $devisions) {
    $output[] = '<a href="'.$devisions.'">'.$chunk.'</a>';
}

print_r($output);
```

The result is not so nice. I get so many errors that I don't know where to start.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why is there no: `<a href='1/2/3/4'>4</a>` ?

Comment: was a mistake. However that isn't the main problem :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

First [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into an array, which will look something like this:

```
Array (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 4
)
```

Then [`count()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) the array to get the amount of parts which you have.

After this you can simply use a for loop where you can always slice a bigger array part from the array with [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) it again into a string.

Means in the loop this happens:

```
              |                   array_slice()                 |        implode()
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1. iteration: | Array ( [0] => 1 )                              |          1
2. iteration: | Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 )                     |          1/2
3. iteration: | Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )            |          1/2/3
4. iteration: | Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )   |          1/2/3/4
```

Code:

```
<?php

    $file_dir = "1/2/3/4";
    $parts = explode("/", $file_dir);
    $amount = count($parts);

    for($i = 1; $i <= $amount; $i++)
        echo "<a href='" . implode("/", array_slice($parts, 0, $i)) . "'>" . $parts[$i-1] . "</a>";

?>
```

output:

```
<a href='1'>1</a>
<a href='1/2'>2</a>
<a href='1/2/3'>3</a>
<a href='1/2/3/4'>4</a>
```

Comment: that would be fine, if the order of the directories would be fliped and if there would be some slashes between the 1 and 2 and 3 and 4.

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf I don't really understand what you mean by *fliped* and *some slashes between ...* ?

Comment: sorry that was for an other comment. Your's works good for me. Thank you!

Comment: @sdfsdfsdf You're welcome. (Changed the answer a bit again, just to clearly show what is going on in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

[strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [strrpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and substr seem very suitable for this job.

"Climb" through the occurences of slashes to find the substrings. Use strrpos to get the bit after the last slash of that substring

```
$file_dir = "1/2/3/4";
$index = 0;
while (($index = strpos($file_dir, "/", $index)) !== false) {
    $file = substr($file_dir, 0, $index);
    $last = substr($file, strrpos($file, "/"));
    echo "<a href='$file'>$last</a>/";
}
```

EDIT: My solution misses the rightmost element, after the last slash. One way to fix this is to manually echo it after the loop:

```
$file = substr($file_dir, $index);
echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a>/";
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
<?php
$file_dir = "1/2/3/4";
$ex=explode('/',$file_dir);
foreach($ex as $x){
$href[]=$x;
$output[]="<a href='".implode('/',$href)."'>$x</a>";
}
echo implode('<br />',$output);
?>
```